# Using intellij to debug eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-rcp

I am currently working on eclipse plug-in that involves many modules, and I would like to debug and run this eclipse plug-in from IntelliJ.I open this project in IntelliJ to edit code but when I have to run/debug this project I have to open eclipse IDE and start it from there. How can I use IntelliJ to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this ... but you could try launching the RCP application stand alone but with the remote debug parameters specified for in your application's .ini file.

Then just point IntelliJ to the appropriate source and attach it's debugger to the running app.

Comment: Good suggestion, remote debugging is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? Eclipse has multiple tools for the plugin development that you will miss in IntelliJ. Also you need to build your plugin as product headless and then attach a debugger to it.

In my opinion it doesn't worth the effort. I would install Eclipse and devolop with eclipse.